# Cypher query not returning the nodes it should return

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two nodes that belong to one of the two labels:Class or Method, as is encircled in yellow in the two images here. The cypher queries to look for *Method* labelled nodes are working properly in all cases. However, quite strangely, the cypher queries to return *Class* labelled nodes give empty results when using properties to select certain nodes. [image]

In the image above, it can be seen that the query  ***Match (n:Class{`Cycles`:"52888"}) return n*** that is encircled in red, gives nothing, although such a node exist as is encircled in green. It is to be noted that a query for the *Class* nodes without the use of property runs fine.
The problem became even more confusing when similar query worked absolutely correctly for *Method* labelled nodes even with use of property to select certain nodes as is visible in the image below. [image]
Can anyone explain why the Cypher queries are behaving differently with the *Class* labelled nodes and what is the solution to the problem.

Comment: Is the "Cycles" property value a String?

Comment: Yes, it is a string @Luanne

Comment: What does match (c:Class) return distinct keys(c) return?

Comment: It returns the following Luanne - 
[Cycles, % of total time taken, % of cumulative time taken, Calls+Recursive, Name of the class]

Comment: I also would have guessed that `Cycles` is a long and not a string.  If this were the case, then matching on the string would fail and return nothing.   I notice you're using backticks on property names where not strictly required.  Is it possible that the *property name* contains some strangeness?   I.e. if the property name were "Cycles " (with an extra space) then naturally the query's failure would make sense.   Numeric properties being strings raises other possible problems like space padding as Michael suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is a space before or after the number?

Try

```
MATCH (n:Class) WHERE trim(n.Cycles) = "52888" RETURN n
```

Answer (score 0):

If the property of Cycles is Long, use the Query

```html
MATCH (n:Class) WHERE n.Cycles = 52888 RETURN n
```

If the property of Cycles is String, use the Query

```html
MATCH (n:Class) WHERE n.Cycles = "52888" RETURN n
```